# Create a colored shadow around a shape in android xml

Tags: android

What is the recommended approach for creating a shadow effect around a shape in Android xml? I have come across tutorials and posts that simply add a non-transparent (black/grey) layer behind the shape, but I want my shadow to be more realistic with some transparency, as using elevation. I am hesitant to use elevation because I want more control over the shadow's direction and color.

As an example, let's consider a specific shape.

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Now I want a shadow to its upper right corner, in red, with a size of 5dp.